# should i lock local variable in multi-threading?

Tags: c#, multithreading, local-variables

I am testing simple caching logic in c#. Here is my CacheManager class:

```
public class CacheManager
{
    static List<string> _list = new List<string>();
    static readonly object _syncobject = new object();

    public static void ReloadList()
    {
        List<string> list = new List<string>();

        Random r = new Random();
        var count = r.Next(10);

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            list.Add("list" + i);
        }

        //lock (_syncobject)
        {
            _list = list;
        }

    }


    public static IEnumerable<string> GetList()
    {
        //lock (_syncobject)
        {
            return _list;
        }
    }

}
```

Below is the class which spawns many threads consuming CacheManager:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        //threads for re-loading the list
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            Thread reloadThread = new Thread(ReloadList);
            reloadThread.Start();
        }

        //threads for getting the list
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Thread tget = new Thread(PrintList);
            tget.Start();
        }

        //threads for getting the list and storing in local variable then use it
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Thread tget = new Thread(PrintListWithLocalVariable);
            tget.Start();
        }

        Console.ReadKey();

    }

    private static void ReloadList()
    {
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Reloading **********");
            CacheManager.ReloadList();

        } while (true);
    }

    private static void PrintList()
    {
        do
        {
            foreach (var item in CacheManager.GetList())
            {
                if (item == null)
                    throw new Exception("i == null");

                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }

        } while (true);
    }

    private static void PrintListWithLocalVariable()
    {
        do
        {
            var list = CacheManager.GetList();
            foreach (var listitem in list)
            {
                var i = list.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Equals(listitem));
                if (i == null)
                    throw new Exception("i == null");
                Console.WriteLine("Printing with Local variable:" + listitem);
            }

        } while (true);
    }


}
```

My understanding was we should lock the _list variable in CacheManager, but doesn't look like we need that. I ran the above test for an hour or so but didn't get any error. While ReloadThread is reloading the random number of list items, other threads which are looping through the list, i thought might have issues. Can anybody explain me why the program is running without issues?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to invent your own cache? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx . Also, try using a ConcurrentCollection. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: FYI, `_list` is not a "local" variable.

Comment: The explanation is: because you got lucky. You may be lucky the next 100 times you run this. But it *will* turn and bite you in uncomfortable places as soon as you need it to work properly;

Answer (score 2):

`_list` is a static variable, meaning that every instance of `CacheManager` will share the same instance of `_list`.  Access to `_list` should indeed be locked to prevent concurrency issues.  As someone mentioned in a comment, a `ConcurrentCollection` should be used instead of `List(of T)` as well, as `List(of T)` is not thread-safe.

Comment: in fact i added lock in my production logic, but before that i was testing it and without locks the logic ran fine for sometime and that made me post this question whether i am missing anything. ConcurrentCollection may not be useful here as i am not adding and getting items from lists. In the ReloadList logic i am just setting the class variable with function variable. And while returning out i am returning IEnumerable, which , i believe creates a copy for a consumer.

Comment: Setting the return type to IEnumerable(of T) does not make a copy of `_list`.  It just returns it as a less-derived type.  If you wanted a copy of `_list` returned, then you could change your getter code to `return _list.ToArray();`, which will copy the list (but not the objects in it).  A better course of action might be to return it as read-only using `return _list.ToList().AsReadOnly();` (ToList() will also copy the original List).